# MySQL Array fetch not working

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a WHILE loop to create a set of 4 tabs with tab titles I get from the DB. I also have a field named tab_id (1,2,3,4) inside the DB.

When I run this code the tab_id is "1" for all 4 rows...but the tab titles display correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
  while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       if ($rows['tab_id'] = 1) { ?>
         <li class="active"><a href="#tab<? echo $rows['tab_id']; ?>" 
         role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ><? echo $rows['tab_title']; ?></a>
         </li>
      <?php } else { ?>        
         <li><a href="#tab<? echo $rows['tab_id']; ?>" role="tab" data-
          toggle="tab" ><? echo $rows['tab_title']; ?></a></li>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: Check your if statement. You use = as your comparison operator when it should be == . That's why it always returns the same tab_id.

Comment: Karlo - thank you! That worked. However - the tabs are printing in reverse order...4.3.2.1. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: You can add  ORDER BY tab_id ASC in your sql string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `=` is an assignment operator in php.  So php thinks you are saying "Declare `$rows['tab_id']` as `1`, does `1` loosely evaluate as `true`?" ...the answer is "yes", so the condition always returns `true`.  (This is the same logic occurring in the `while` loop on the previous line.)

To make a loose comparison (that is all that is needed) you merely need to add one more `=` to make `==`.

Further advice is that your snippet can be written more D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself).  You are only modifying `class="active"` so there is no need to rewrite the entire `<li>` tag.

Suggested code:

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    <li<?php if($rows['tab_id'] == 1) echo ' class="active"'; ?>><a href="#tab<? echo $rows['tab_id']; ?>" 
     role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ><? echo $rows['tab_title']; ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

or

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<li",($rows['tab_id'] == 1 ? ' class="active"' : ''),">";
        echo "<a href=\"#tab{$rows['tab_id']}\" role=\"tab\" data-toggle=\"tab\" >{$rows['tab_title']}</a>";
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   if ($rows['tab_id'] ==1) { ?>
     <li class="active"><a href="#tab<? echo $rows['tab_id']; ?>" 
     role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ><? echo $rows['tab_title']; ?></a>
     </li>
  <?php } else { ?>        
     <li><a href="#tab<? echo $rows['tab_id']; ?>" role="tab" data-
      toggle="tab" ><? echo $rows['tab_title']; ?></a></li>
```